# Hash function for vector<double>

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

First, I am wondering if anyone knows of a hash function for vector representing an n-D vector?

Second, is there a similar hash function where I can specify a resolution such that two "close" vectors hash to the same value?

For example:
given resolution r = 0.01
q1 = {1.01, 2.3}
q2 = {1.01, 2.31} 
would hash to the same value.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: by definition, that's not a hash function. I suppose you could do floor(x*10) for each one and then use a normal hash function though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would work for you?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// simple variant of ELF hash ... but you could use any general-purpose hashing algorithm here instead
static int GetHashCodeForBytes(const char * bytes, int numBytes)
{
   unsigned long h = 0, g;
   for (int i=0; i<numBytes; i++)
   {
      h = ( h << 4 ) + bytes[i];
      if (g = h & 0xF0000000L) {h ^= g >> 24;}
      h &= ~g;
   }
   return h;
}

static int GetHashForDouble(double v)
{
   return GetHashCodeForBytes((const char *)&v, sizeof(v));
}

static int GetHashForDoubleVector(const vector<double> & v)
{
   int ret = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) ret += ((i+1)*(GetHashForDouble(v[i])));
   return ret;
}

int main()
{
   vector<double> vec;
   vec.push_back(3.14159);
   vec.push_back(2.34567);
   cout << "  Hash code for test vec is:  " << GetHashForDoubleVector(vec) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```